# What level of correlation coefficient suggests correlation?

Tags: correlation

In Python (and Numpy), I recently did:-

```
a = np.random.randint(0,256,1000)

b = np.random.randint(0,256,1000)
```

and when I calculate the correlation coefficient $r$ using:-

```
np.corrcoef( a,b )
```

I get a value of 0.07944437.  Rounded, that's 0.08, 8% or about $1 \over 13$ th.

$r$ is said to typically range -1.0 thru 0.0 to +1.0.  I've never had a 0.0 and don't think that it's possible as random correlations can always be found between any two series. It's like asking "*How small is small?*" 0.08 doesn't seem that small. Yet clearly $a$ is not correlated to $b$ as both originate from the good quality Mersenne Twister deep inside Python.

So if $r = 0$ is empirically impossible, when does it actually become significant and suggest a real correlation?

---

Note 1.  There is of course the [68–95–99.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) rule. This covers a $3 \delta$ range of certainty. The atomic guys use $5 \delta$ to confirm a discovery. Do  signal guys do anything similar, and if so, how would they apply it?

Note 2. With the greatest of respect, [How do I know quantitatively if the correlation of two time series is significant?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36171/15129) seems ambiguous.

Comment: It is a percentage between -100% (completely negatively correlated) and +100%. So 99% is significant and 8% is insignificant. Random noise will provide such a correlation and in fact you can derive the signal to noise ratio from the correlation coefficient. So your question of how significant it is would be the same as asking how good of a grade and 82% on a test is.

Comment: r is a parameter and you can calculate a confidence  region or p value for it. The range where something is uncorrelated as a hypothesis is r=0 and you can use a two sided p value as your test or the exceedance probability of a confidence region.  You are looking for a small probability that r=0.  The actual threshold is application dependent

Comment: Hi: if you want to implement the suggestion of Stanley, you need to transform r in order order to obtain something closer to normality. I forget the details but look up fisher transform or hopefully this is adequate.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation.

Comment: @DanBoschen See note 1.  An 8% correlation is well outside of most scientists'  accepted levels of confidence in proving a hypothesis. They would reject the null hypothesis @ < $2 \delta$.  A music test ultimately officiated by a politician is not a good counter example.

Comment: @PaulUszak I agree- I said I would consider it insignificant.

Comment: I think the correlation process itself (being a multiply and accumulate) can be viewed as a low pass filter of your input signals (white noise) with a BW inversely proportional to the number of samples accumulated, N.  If so, increasing N and the resulting correlation should go down accordingly. (This may only apply to correlating with a specific signal such as a tone; I am not entirely sure how this would actually result when both inputs are noise as you did)

Comment: there are definitely ways of getting exactly zero as a correlation between to signals.  try correlating a sine to a cosine of the same frequency, using an integer number of cycles in the correlation summation.  or try correlating two sinusoids of different frequencies using a summation length that is an integer number of cycles for each of the two sinusoids.

Comment: But I think ultimately to answer the question, the correlation is a metric and it likely is the answer on its own; as in the correlation was x... without providing additional (subjective) indications of significance or existence.  (My analogy of a test result was to try an express that--- I got an 82% on the test; that is the qualitative result).

Comment: @markleeds $Fisher(0.08) \approx 0.08$ unfortunately.  The arctanh formula only seems to have consequence >> 0.08.

Comment: Correlation coefficients can be and often are complex valued in Signal Processing

Comment: Thanks Stanley. I forgot about the complex possibility. Paul: The value really depends on the context. In fact, capturing .08^2 = 0.064 in a financial application where one is capturing "return" say, would be considered decent. I would use Dilip's rule below and keep the context in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a -1 next to Dilip's answer. It seems reasonable to me aside from the lack of mention of context.

Comment: @markleeds I wouldn't worry too much about downvotes; drive-by downvotes (those that leave no comment as to why the post is considered "not useful") are plentiful in stackexchange sites and a particularly favorite sport on dsp.SE.

Comment: @markleeds $0.08^2 = 0.0064 = 0.64\%$, not $0.064=6.4\%$.  Would $0.64\%$ also be considered a decent "return"  in a financial application?

Comment: Hi Dilip: Thanks for heads up on downbvotes. you are correct. I made a made multiplication error. and yes, .64 percent would NOT be considered a decent correlation ( resulting from a regression that predicts returns )  in a financial application. But 6.4 percent might be.

Answer (score -2):

One way to look at it is that $r^2$ (yes, I do mean $r^2$, not $r$ or $|r|$) is the *fraction* of the variance of the target (the series A) that is *explained* by the estimator (a linear function $\alpha + \beta B$ of the series B).  Note that if Series A had variance $\sigma^2$, then the variance of $(A - (\alpha + \beta B))^2$ (what B cannot explain about A) is $(1-r^2)\sigma^2$.  So, if $|r| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.707\ldots$, *less than half the variance has been explained*, and so one viewpoint is that a correlation of less than $70\%$ or so suggests that the *linear estimator* being considered here is not all that great.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get this.  Are you suggesting 70% as a confidence level? To my mind when making a serious decision, 70% ~ 50%. That's evens. Isn't an interval of 0.5% commonplace in the classical sciences, and 0.0001% at CERN?

Comment: No, the question that you ask is "Is this correlation _significant_?" which has a straghtforward Yes or No answer, and my recommendation is that any $|r|$ smaller than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ should be considered insignificant.  If you want a "confidence interval", take it to be $[-1,-1/\sqrt{2}] \cup [1/\sqrt{2}, +1]$; an $r$ value in the stated interval should be considered significant, while anything else should be considered insignificant.